# How to rename a directory from R, when that is not empty?

Tags: r

How can I rename a directory from R?

I tried:

```
Warning message:
In file.rename(from = sprintf("content/%s-content", pu_name), to = sprintf("content/%s",  :
  cannot rename file 'content/pu.train2-content' to 'content/train2', reason 'Directory not empty'
```

Comment: From the help file, `?file.rename`, "On Windows, file.rename can move files but not directories between volumes. On platforms which allow directories to be renamed, typically neither or both of from and to must a directory, and if to exists it must be an empty directory."

Comment: I see, `file.rename` may not be the right solution

Comment: In other words, `file.rename()` works fine on Windows for renaming folders, as long as it's not across different drives. For most of (my) use cases, it's a nice and fast solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `shell` in order to pass an OS specific command to change it:

```
shell(paste('rename', 
            sprintf("content/%s-content", pu_name),
            sprintf("content/%s", other_name)))
```

And it should work without needing an empty directory.